# Finding $c$ such that $\mathbb{P}\left[ \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{X_n}{n} = c \right] = 1$

Tags: probability-theory, law-of-large-numbers

For a given $X_n$ sequence of random variables such that for every $n$, $X_n\sim\mathsf{Geo}\left(\frac{1}{9n}\right)$. I am asked to find $c$ such that $$\mathbb{P}\left[ \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{X_n}{n} = c \right] = 1$$

So my idea is to use the large number law by that I will define an $X_k'$ for $k =1,2,...,n$ such that $$\sum_{k=1}^{k=n}X_k' \sim\mathsf{Geo}\left(\frac{1}{9n}\right)$$ but how do I find such $X_k'$?

Comment: is Geo a geometric distribution? and is it number of trials or number of failures before success ?

Comment: @DanielAdams Yes it means geometric distribution with probability for success of $\frac{1}{9n}$

Comment: Isn't it intuitive that $c=9$?

Comment: @BenjaminWang nope, would you like to explain?

Comment: $EX_n=9n-1$ so $\frac {EX_n} {n} \to 9$ So you expect $c$ to be $9$. Now prove that $c=9$ really works.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I am not sure why there is $9n-1$, where is the minus one came?

Comment: @Sagigever remember there are two slightly different ways to define a geometric, I asked you this in my first comment.

Comment: @DanielAdams we are using the method of counting the numbers of trials untill the first success, I didn't even know about the second definition. nice to know that

Comment: Also you're asking for almost sure convergence here, which is a pretty strict form of convergence. Can you assume the $X_n$ are independent? If not then I suspect the result is not true.